# How to retain styles within dynamic routes in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, css, laravel-5.4

In the application I built I have a view called  main (http://127.0.0.1:8000/main). Following is how I load the view file from Route file, web.php.

```
Route::resources(['/main' => 'pages\MainController']);
```

Above loads the 'main.blade.php' view controller from the index function of MainController.php file.

```
public function index() {
    return view('pages\'main');
}
```

My problem is, I have an edit button in the view which the href value is set as following.

```
<a href="main/{{$data->id}}/edit" >Edit</a>
```

Click of the above will direct me to 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/1/edit' route 
 and this route will not load any styles and javascript files like it was loaded in 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/main' . What is the work around to retain the resource styles and js functionality ?

Following is one example I have linked my resource css in my main layout blade

```
<link href="vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet
```

Comment: If you're using laravel then use the url and asset helpers generator to build the URLs for links and resources. That way laravel can sort out absolute URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the resource URLs within url php function.

```
 {{url('vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}
```

So the complete code is.

```
<link href="{{url('vendors/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

href="{{ URL :: asset ( ' your css path ') }}"

Make sure you css is in public directory